# I just noticed my LaTeX error in a comment but it's been 5 minutes. How can I fix it?

Tags: feature-request, comment

Arghhh! I messed up some LaTeX in a comment, but didn't notice until after 5 minutes had passed and so I can't fix it. Is that it? Is it always going to look ugly and I can't do anything about it?

Comment: Maybe useful in this context: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3234/how-to-copy-mixture-of-text-and-latex-formulas-in-a-comment

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Copy the text, delete the comment, and add a new comment.

Comment: Wow. Duh. That should have been obvious but...maybe the delete button is too small for my eyesight.

Comment: But...then why institute a 5 minute limit if it's so easy to go around it? I'm also surprised my question wasn't closed immediately as having been answered in multiples.

Comment: @Mitch: If new comments are posted in the meantime, then your reposted comment appears at a different position, namely at the bottom of the comment thread. This way everyone sees it as a _new_ comment.

Comment: Unlike answers, other people don't get to see the history of comment editing. The five-minute rule makes it less likely to have a confusing thread in which the assumed chronological order of discussion becomes false.